# Admin Server and Managed Server set to Production mode in Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, product, weblogic12c

I am very new to Weblogic and have a question.

I have a Admin Server and four Managed Server .

I want to set Prodcution Mode to true in Admin Domain , would this also run all the managed servers in Production Mode ?

Also, does this change require weblogic restart ?

I am using Weblogic 12c.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All servers in the domain run in production or development mode, it is a domain wide setting. Managed servers refer to the admin server to determine their run mode. And yes you will need to restart all servers in your domain for this to take affect.

Google is your friend - this was the first link that came up:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/domainconfig/ChangeRuntimeModes.html